# Gradle sync failed: Cause: startup failed (Basic functionality not working)

Tags: android, android-studio-3.1.3

It is my first time to use android studio V 3.1.3
when i finished installation and trying to build this error is shown

[image: Error]

it said that "Basic functioality not working correctly such as building and debugging "
i do not known how to solve it

i use a local gradle distribution like this
[image: Trying this]

Then press on sync project with gradles files
but this error is still shown.

It works well but after that this error is happened
[image: Err]

any help
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**I also have the same problems as you,Now I have solved it.**

The following are the steps to be solved

1. Exit Android Studio.
2. Delete the .gradle folder eg: C:\Users{userName}}.gradle
3. Restart androidStudio and wait a moment.

Comment: Yes i tried it an d it worked but look at the update , There is another error

Comment: if you want tot report to Google then click on Report To Google OR Close. it's just like alert dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
Android studio -> File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart
```

Comment: Yes i tried it an d it worked but look at the update , There is another error

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the .gradle folder was unsuccessfull for me.
Still waiting for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

you should go to `settings > build,execution,Deployment > build tool  > gradle`

and the change the user gradle home that to path of environment variable of JAVA-HOME Address
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw5kF.png)
and then change gradle JDK to Embedded JDK it will solve your problem